# What other forms of verb can I use in "I see him swelling with pride"?

Tags: verbs

What part of speech is this?

> I see him swelling with pride.

What is "swelling with pride"? What other forms of verb can I use here? e.g.: swell

Does it have a name, like a verb?

Comment: _Swelling_ is the present participle of the verb _to swell_. To 'swell with pride' is to become so filled with pride that you metaphorically 'swell up' with it.

Answer (score 2):

I see him swelling with pride. = I see him *and he is* swelling with pride.

Compare: I see him drunk = I see him *and he is* drunk.

To me, *swelling with pride* is a participle phrase acting as a depictive, i.e. an adjectival free modifier.